# Exercise 50 :: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex50.html (error while running hello world using sinatra"

Tags: ruby, sinatra

i am trying the [ex:50 of  learning Ruby the hard way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex50.html) ..which involves creating hello_world application using 'sinatra'
i am getting errors like :

```
 ruby lib/gothonweb.rb
    lib/gothonweb.rb:5:in `<module:Gothonweb>': undefined method `get' for Gothonweb:Module             (NoMethodError)
    from lib/gothonweb.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I suppose the book has defined Gothonweb module declared earlier, which you don't have on your machine. Pasting your code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not something you've done, the code given doesn't work:

```
require_relative "gothonweb/version"
require "sinatra"

module Gothonweb
  get '/' do
    greeting = "Hello, World!"
    return greeting
  end
end
```

This won't work because it's wrapped in a module. Try this:

```
require_relative "gothonweb/version"
require "sinatra"

get '/' do
  greeting = "Hello, World!"
  greeting # there's no need for the return here,
           # the last expression is the return value
end
```

Comment: This doesn’t work with the current version of Sinatra (1.4), but it did with version 1.3. The other way to get it to work would be to install an earlier version of Sinatra (`$ gem install sinatra -v 1.3.6`) and then add `gem 'sinatra', '1.3.6'` to the top of the file to ensure you load that version.